# Inconsistent behavior from .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I include jQuery in the console and run this snippet against Google.com, what should happen is that numbered tags appear next to all the anchor elements. Which works fine.

But when you click those tags, it should act as if you clicked the element each tag appears to the left of. Most of them work-- the direct anchors that redirect to a new page, that works fine.

But you'll see there's one, the little square of squares image next to the "Images" anchor, which isn't a direct anchor but rather has a click event on it which shows the other apps in a little pop-up window, and that's where the issue is.

If I give it an id and use `.click()` directly on it in the console, it works perfectly. But with this code....the `.click()` is simply not working! I can't seem to determine why.

```
var n = 1;
$('a').each(function(){
    //create and place numbered tag elements-- works fine
    var id = n;
    var a = $(this).offset();
    $('body').append('<span class="numTag" id="' + id + '" style="background:white; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10pt; position:absolute; z-index:999;">' + id + '</span>');
    $('#'+id).css({left: a.left - 25, top: a.top});

    //create click event on each tag-- doesn't quite completely work
    var self = this;
    $('#'+id).click(function(){
        self.click();
    });
    n++;
});
```

Note, this is only designed to work in Chrome; it's part of an extension. Other browsers do not matter here.

Comment: You may want to note that id values are not supposed to start with a number.

Comment: you don't actually need an id here at all, if you create the element directly, add the behavior, and then append it to the DOM.  but hm, weird.

Comment: The id is used for separate functionality not relevant here.

Comment: @jfriend00 - in HTML5 it's fine.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger for debugging the code line by line, and watching all variables contents?

Comment: Hello are you getting any error **id="' + id + '"**  should be **id='" + id + "'** means double quote should be inside

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?!

Comment: @user2284570 yes. gained nothing.

Comment: Notice that if you use setTimeout(function() { self.click(); }, 10); it works. I'm guessing it has something to do with you using click inside click.

Comment: @EranH. make that an answer and the bounty is yours. You're dead on. First tip that worked for me, out of all these answers. Now that you say it, I remember encountering similar behavior once before. Thanks so much.

Comment: JavaScript debugger? did you even deeped in the libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From EranH's comment under the question, this solution works perfectly. I can't say I understand why, but there you have it.

> Notice that if you use setTimeout(function() { self.click(); }, 10);
>   it works. I'm guessing it has something to do with you using click
>   inside click.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I don't know exactly why your code didn't work, but this seems to work:</del>

<del>Sorry, was looking at the wrong number box! Doesn't work :(</del>

Ok this seems to affect the problem, but not solve it:

```
var n = 1;
$('a').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).offset();
    var $num = $('<span class="numTag" id="number_' + n + '" style="background:white; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10pt; position:absolute; z-index:999;">' + n + '</span>');
    $('body').append($num);
    $num.css({left: a.left - 25, top: a.top});
    var that = this;
    $num.on('click' ,function () {
        var e = new MouseEvent('click', {
          'view': window,
          'bubbles': true,
          'cancelable': false
        });
        that.dispatchEvent(e);
    });
    n++;
});
```

What happens is that browser follows the link (href) the same way as if no other click event were in place. I suspect that the other events get triggered too, but the page get's reloaded in the same moment.

If you set `cancelable` to `true` it won't work. So I guess that the event get's canceled somewhere. But why doesn't it show the popup-tooltip box is beyond me...

Comment: That's a very clever insight and I think that's a step in the right direction. I'm thinking how to approach this...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the binding, the click event is not attached to the dynamically created item. you should use on() (previously live() ) to attache the binding to the element you created:

The following jQuery.On signature:

```
  $(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );
```

in your case:

```
//define the span first
createdSpan = "<span class="numTag" id="number_' + n + '" style="background:white; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10pt; position:absolute; z-index:999;">' + n + '</span>'"
//append it here
$('body').append(createdSpan)
//attache/bind the event 
$(createdSpan).on( 'click', function(){
    this.trigger( 'click' );
 });
```

Comment: can you explain the down vote ? i am sure the problem is with your binding !

Comment: Your code does not delegate ; plus it adds html to the body, then creates a new node, binds a click handler to it, and throws it away.

Comment: this is just a snippet to show him that the problem is the binding, I am not writing his code !

Answer (score 0):

The following code "works" (tested on github's front page - executed from Chromium console) :

```
// delegate event handling in one place :
$('body').on('click', '.numTag', function(){
    var anchor = $(this).data('link');
    $(anchor).click();
});

// you can use the loop counter to have a number associated with each 'a' tag
$('a').each(function(n){
    //create and place numbered tag elements
    var a = $(this).offset();

    var $numTag = $('<span class="numTag" style="background:white; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10pt; position:absolute; z-index:999;">'+n+'</span>');
    $numTag.data('link', this);
    $numTag.css({left: a.left - 25, top: a.top});
    $('body').append( $numTag );
});
```

A simple remark : if you add your tags as children of the 'a' anchors, you don't need to manually handle the click events :

```
$('a').each(function(n){
    //create and place numbered tag elements
    var a = $(this).offset();

    var $numTag = $('<span class="numTag" style="background:white; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10pt; position:absolute; z-index:999;">'+n+'</span>');
    $numTag.css({left: a.left - 25, top: a.top});
    $(this).append( $numTag );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending the `span` within the anchor tag that is being iterated through, rather than the `body`, worked for me.

```
var n = 1;
$('a').each(function(){
    var id = n;
    $(this).append('<span class="numTag" style="background:white; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10pt; position:absolute; z-index:999;">' + id + '</span>');
    n++;
});
```

Comment: When I tried this, it didn't put up a numbered tag for the "box of boxes" at all. Confused :( . . . . this makes sense in theory.

Comment: Do the numbered boxes append for the rest of the links? Just tested it again and I got a six in the box nested in the App button.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why the click doesn't work on those particular links either. The page probably cancels out the default behaviour to do its own js thingy.

If I try to fire the event manually on the Images link as a test nothing happens either, so this is not a binding issue:

```
$('.gb_b').eq(2).click()
```

($('.gb_b').eq(2) is the Images link here on my Belgian google.be page)

Here is a workaround, instead of calling the click event you can do a javascript redirect to the href attribute pulled from the clicked anchor. Don't know if this works in a chrome extension context as I don't have any experience with this.

```
var n = 1;
$('a').each(function(){
    //create and place numbered tag elements-- works fine
    var id = n;
    var a = $(this).offset();
    $('body').append('<span class="numTag" id="n' + id + '" style="background:white; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10pt; position:absolute; z-index:999;">' + id + '</span>');
    $('#n'+id).css({left: a.left - 25, top: a.top});

    //create click event on each tag-- doesn't quite completely work
    var self = this;
    $('#n'+id).click(function(){
        window.location = $(self).attr('href');
    });
    n++;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you change to this much simpler code that should work fine.  I'm not sure exactly why your existing code doesn't work, but there could be an issue with either your illegal id values (can't start with a number) or with the `.click()` DOM method not existing on all types of objects.  In either case, this simpler code avoids both of those issues:

```
$('a').each(function(index){
    var a = $(this).offset();
    var item = $('<span class="numTag" style="background:white; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10pt; position:absolute; z-index:999;">' + (index + 1) + '</span>');
    item.css({left: a.left - 25, top: a.top});
    item.appendTo(document.body);
    var self = $(this);
    item.click(function(){
        self.click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, if that were the case, I would expect that it wouldn't work at all for any of them anchors, rather than only not working in the case of this one element.

Comment: @Aerovistae - did you try my code suggestion?  `.click()` for DOM elements is an HTML5 addition and has not been supported on all types of elements in all browsers.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click for some info.  Also, did you try making the id value legal as I suggested?

Comment: @Aerovistae - please try my simpler version of code that avoids a couple pitfalls you have in your original one.

Comment: Without researching the topic of `click()` on DOM elements, I would choose jQuery's implementation over vanilla JS anytime. You never know which browser has it's own cemented reasons for behaving (just a bit) differently. And it is more likely that jQuery guys have taken that into account then not, IMO anyway. Of course, when building for one browser only, the argument is invalid.